# KVM copy contents of image into raw smaller LVM2 partition

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, lvm, qemu

I have a KVM guest, running on a KVM host...both Gentoo Linux.

The guest is called webserver.img. It is 21 gigs large, but I am only using 5 gigs inside the image.

I want to make a logical volume with **NO** filesystem(raw) and have the size about 10gigs, place the contents of webserver.img on it, and boot from the raw logical volume.

How could I get the contents of webserver.img onto ....for example.../dev/mapper/logical_volume1?

I thought about dd if=webserver.img of=/dev/mapper/logical_volume1 but I am worried that will copy over the filesystem or there might be some corruption.

Comment: Does your `webserver.img` have a partition table? Could you check output of `fdisk -l webserver.img` or `file webserver.img`

Comment: Why not use a proper filesystem rather than a disk image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use image files (as you do now) and you can export block devices (as such). I am not sure whether you can safely write an image file to a block device and use the block device as an image file then. Probably wouldn't make much sense anyway.

You should stay with image files.

1. make a file system on the LV (e.g. `mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/logical_volume1`
2. mount the volume (`mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/logical_volume1 /mnt/logical_volume1`)
3. shutdown the VM
4. copy the image file (`cp -p /path/to/webserver.img /mnt/logical_volume1`)
5. adapt the VM configuration to the new path (rename the old image file to be sure)
6. restart the VM